# Setting a cover image for a specific category in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a Wordpress theme and they provide a code snippet to set a header image for all listings where the user has not set an image for themselves.
I have looked in the documentation of the theme and I can't find any support on setting an image for a specific category.
I have four categories of listings and I would like a different image to show for each category.
Is this possible?

This is the code snippet below.
Any help would be great.
Thanks.

```
<?php
/**
* Listify - Default Image for Listings
*/
function custom_default_listify_cover_image( $image, $args ) {
global $post;

if ( $image || $post->post_type != 'job_listing' ) {
    return $image;
}

$image = array( 'http://yourwebsite.com/images/default-image.png' );

return $image;
}
add_filter( 'listify_cover_image', 'custom_default_listify_cover_image', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THis will be helpful for your work : 
https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/how-to-add-feature-images-to-your-wordpress-categories/?omtr=b&utm_expid=3606929-101._J2UGKNuQ6e7Of8gblmOTA.1&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F